# Where can I find world covid death or vaccination datasets which include age group columns?

Tags: data-request

I have a dataset showing age groups of 60 > but couldn't understand the data values. I'm seeking a dataset with more age ranges or how to read the one below.

I have [used this Dataset](https://ourworldindata.org/explorers/coronavirus-data-explorer?zoomToSelection=true&time=2020-03-01..latest&facet=none&pickerSort=asc&pickerMetric=location&hideControls=false&Metric=Confirmed%20deaths&Interval=7-day%20rolling%20average&Relative%20to%20Population=true&Color%20by%20test%20positivity=false&country=IND%7EUSA%7EGBR%7ECAN%7EDEU%7EFRA).

Answer (score 1):

[Unicef has a write up on children covid deaths](https://data.unicef.org/resources/covid-19-confirmed-cases-and-deaths-dashboard/), and the [Raw data set found on Github](https://github.com/timriffe/covid_age).

The [Our World in Data covid dataset](https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data) only reports the median age, and the percentage of people aged 65 older, and aged 70 older. The median age is the age where half of the deaths are older and half are younger.

I'm assuming this was to simplify the data. Less age ranges, may be thought to make the data more approachable.